# PHP - get multiple rows from MySQL and JSON-encode them

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a `JSON` array from the `MySQL` database. Here's the part of the code that fetches rows and add them into the array.

```
<?php
if($rowcount > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($fetch)) {
        $row_array["uid"] = $row['unique_id'];
        $row_array["users"]["name"] = $row['name'];
        $row_array["users"]["email"] = $row['email'];
        array_push($users, $row_array);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($fetch);
    echo json_encode($users);
}
?>
```

This part is causing an error, showing the following message.

> **Notice**:  Undefined index: unique_id in
>   **/storage/h3/859/644859/public_html/searchfriends.php** on line
>   **20**
>                                                                          
>                                                                          **Notice**:  Undefined index: name in
>   **/storage/h3/859/644859/public_html/searchfriends.php** on line
>   **21**
>                                                                          
>                                                                          **Notice**:  Undefined index: email in
>   **/storage/h3/859/644859/public_html/searchfriends.php** on line
>   **22**

Each line represents the following parts.

```
$row_array["uid"] = $row['unique_id'];
$row_array["users"]["name"] = $row['name'];
$row_array["users"]["email"] = $row['email'];
```

So, I believe I did not properly format the array. How should I fix it correct?

Comment: look at the thable, there is a filed called "unique_id" ?

Comment: yes, there is no problem with the db'

Comment: I just checked out the table and the column names are fine. They are literally `unique_id`, `name`, and `email`. The order is a little bit different though.

Comment: put index value instead of name of the table column like 0,1,2 as answer by @Anant use assoc instead row

Comment: @Anant I just fixed the problem with your tip. You saved my day!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Based on manual :-http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php***

It will give you a numeric indexes array. So you have to do like below:-

`$row[0],$row[1].... so on`

***OR***

Best should be change this single line like below:-

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetch)) { 
// instead of mysqli_fetch_row use mysqli_fetch_assoc
```

Comment: Marshall S. Lee glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if($rowcount > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($fetch)) {
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($fetch); //  check here you have columns of email ,name etc.. or not
 die;
        $row_array["uid"] = $row['unique_id'];
        $row_array["users"]["name"] = $row['name'];
        $row_array["users"]["email"] = $row['email'];
        array_push($users, $row_array);
    }
    mysqli_free_result($fetch);
    echo json_encode($users);
}
?>
```